# Why does the order of the arguments passed in List.sort differ from the order of the parameters in the compare method?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, compare, comparator

Why does the order of the arguments passed in List.sort differ from the order of the parameters in the compare method?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
class SampleComparator implements Comparator<Sample> {
    public int compare(Sample param1, Sample param2) {
        System.out.println("1st param is " + param1.getNum() + ", 2nd param is " + param2.getNum()); // 1st param is 2, 2nd param is 1

        if (param1.getNum() < param2.getNum()) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (param1.getNum() > param2.getNum()) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
class Sample {
    private int num;
    public Sample(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }
    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }
}
public class SampleSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sample[] obj = {
                new Sample(1), //arg is 1
                new Sample(2)  //arg is 2
        };
        List<Sample> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(obj));
        list.sort(new SampleComparator());
    }
}
```

I expected this.
1st arg is 1, 2nd arg is 2

Actual Results.
1st arg is 2, 2nd arg is 1

I saw this but couldn't understand.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-
Thank you, I am a novice and was puzzled by this behavior.
I found the answer.

when the sort method calls the compare method, it passes the arguments in the opposite order, with param2 first and param1 second.
This ordering may seem counterintuitive, but it is deliberate and consistent with the convention used in the Java API. The reason for this convention is to allow for greater flexibility in defining comparators. By swapping the order of the arguments, the compare method can be used to define a comparison in which the first argument is considered greater than the second or vice versa, depending on the needs of the application.

```
class SampleComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    public int compare(String param1, String param2) {
        System.out.println("1st param is " + param1 + ", 2nd param is " + param2); // 1st param is A, 2nd param is B
        return param1.compareTo(param2);
    }
}
public class SampleSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("B"); //arg is "B"
        list.add("A"); //arg is "A"
        list.sort(new SampleComparator());
    }
}
```

Comment: The sorting implementation can pass the arguments in either order, so long as it uses the result appropriately. There's nothing to say that an earlier element in the collection *has* to be passed as the first argument and a later element *has* to be passed as the second argument.

Comment: Why did you expect them to be the same? You don't know how `List.sort` is implemented. Why expect a relationship between the order of elements in the list and the order of the arguments?

Answer (score 1):

Because it doesn't matter. The comparator should be able to return the correct result either way. If it doesn't then your comparator has a bug in it. As for the actual internal reasons, we cant know that without viewing the source code of the particular Java implementation you're using (remember that Java is an open standard and so there are actually multiple implementations of Java, some of which may exhibit this behavior, and others which may not). So make your comparator work the same either way.